# Sync user data in Android with Google Drive

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-api

I have a standalone android app that stores user data in the device. I have this idea to sync the database file with user's google drive account. In this way user can access the same data from multiple devices.

1. Is it a good approach to sync user data?
2. Is there any other option available provided that the app will be free and user should not be charged for any service?

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2c is this is a risky approach. You're relying on Sqlite not storing instance specific data in the database file and there is no write-conflict checking. I would look at something like

- Firebase
- Drive realtime API
- Cloud Sync http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html

which are all designed for that specific purpose.